# Get correct price value

Tags: web3js, javascript, uniswap, ethereumjs

I am attempting to get the current prices for some tokens from Uniswap and SushiSwap.

I am using this function:

```
  async getBuyPrice() {
    const pathToBuy = await this.routerContract.methods.getAmountsIn(
      this.swapAmount, 
      [ this.swapTo, this.swapFrom ], 
    ).call();
    return Math.floor(ethers.utils.parseUnits(pathToBuy[0], this.decimal) * 100) / 100
  }
```

For example for USDT I am passing in a swap amount of '1000000000000000000' to equal one Eth a decimal of 6 to equal what the USDT contract says and then the contract addresses.

For example:

```
swapAmount : '1000000000000000000',
swapTo:'0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2', // weth address
swapFrom: '0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7', // USDT address
decimal: 6
```

This should give me how much 1 WETH is in USDT

This should be something like `1673 USDT` however I get a really long number with no decimal place `WETH / USDT   1678898786000000`

Comment: `1678898786000000 / 1e12` is what you want. Why 12? Because WETH has 18 decimals and USDT have 6, and 18 - 6 = 12.

Comment: @kfx Thanks! Are there any docs on this?